# Angular router navigation to children routes

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-router-params

This is how a route in my app-routing-module looks like.

```
{
    path: 'subjects/:subjectId', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'slideset/:slidesetId',
        component: MainComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'exercise/:exerciseId',
        component: MainComponent
      }
    ]
  }
```

Now in one of my components when I try to do this,

```
this.router.navigate(['/subjects', studyFile.subjectId, studyFile.id ]);
```

it never redirects me to this path `'slideset/:slidesetId'`
I am not been able to figure out why? or is this this right way to navigate to child component?

Comment: where do you do this navigation ? From parent route ?

Comment: Try `this.router.navigate(['subjects', studyFile.subjectId, 'slideset', studyFile.id ]);`

Comment: No, from this route http://localhost:4200/lectures.

Comment: @ArpitMeena cool it works :), but     route.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log('parameters', params);
    }); only logs subjectID

Comment: Cool, we can grab both parent and child params like this,     route.params.subscribe( params => {
      console.log('parameters', params);
    });
    route.firstChild.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log('child Params', params);
    });